# What to do when RDP wont log into windows EC2 instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

After detaching a volume and creating a new instance with more RAM, I can no longer log into the RDP. When I try it says my credentials don't work, even though I copied it directly from the AWS management console.

Other posts have mentioned checking the inbound security rules to make sure they can connect to RDP, and that is not the problem. The IPv4 Public IP is also present, so that's not a problem either. All of the status checks are fine.

Anyone have any ideas about what might be the issue here?

Comment: Hard to know without seeing event logs. You don't have remote access to that do you?

Comment: Is this a custom AMI you are launching from?

Comment: To be honest I don't really know. This is my first time using their cloud services. The original instance didn't have enough RAM to process my script efficiently, so I detached the volume with the files, terminated the instance, and started a new one. Does that make it a custom AMI o_O?

Comment: Ah! If you launched a completely new instance, then you would have been asked to select a Keypair when launching the instance. This Keypair can be used to obtain the Administrator password. See: [Retrieve a Windows Administrator Password After Launching an Instance](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/retrieve-windows-admin-password/) FYI, you can change the Instance Type without creating a new EC2 instance. Simply Stop the instance, change the type and then Start it again.

Comment: I have the key pair though! This is seriously blowing my mind though because I could've saved myself hours and hours if I had just changed the instance type XD.

Comment: Sounds like there might be a few variables to work through. Perhaps we could help you troubleshoot in real time if you drop a line in the [AWS Chatroom](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214788/aws-chat).